# Link to old community go.stackexchange.com now directs to www.golinks.io

Tags: support, hyperlinks

In 2011, I posted a link in the comments of https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5511/60

At the time, this link connected to another question on the same website, which was `go.stackexchange.com`, then an Area51 community in beta about the board game Go. This community was later merged into `boardgames.stackexchange.com`.

The link now directs to `www.golinks.io`.

This may be caused by reappropriating the "go" subdomain for link redirection.

I'm bringing this to your attention to confirm if/how this needs to be adressed. In general, I'm not a big fan of any kind of changes to linking systems. However, the impact here is likely so negligible that no action beyond this documentation is needed.

I was mostly surprised that an external service (golinks.io) is used at all.

Comment: Probably only old comments are affected: this very question is the [only hit for `go.stackexchange.com`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22go.stackexchange.com%22).

Comment: It is weird to redirect to an external (-looking) site if Stack Exchange owns `stackexchange.com` and not just the per-community sub-domains.